# Bootstrap navbar exclude items and never go to two rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've spent hours trying to sort this but can't quite get it right. I want a three column Bootstrap navbar with the following features:-

1. Only the centre column ever collapses to a button
2. The navbar never drops to two rows

So it will look something like

### Column 1    |       Column 2                 |   Column 3

Column 1 will be the brand. Column 2 the menu items (which will collapse to a button if they all don't fit) and Column 3 will be the user profile button or log in/out buttons depending is a user is logged in or not.

Here's the closest I've gotten so far: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alofthedunnes/3up5heny/1/)

It's pretty close but I can't figure out how to stop the navbar going to two rows at certain widths and always ensure the centre column collapses to a button unless all menu items fit. I'm ready to throw my computer in the bin at this stage.

Thanks for looking. Hopefully someone can help as this is driving me up the wall

> **Edit**

Big shout out to vanburenx for getting me on the right path.

I've made some adjustments to the original code and as per my comments below, I can't figure out what exactly is causing the collapse and now also, what is making the menu items on the right drop below each other. Here's 2 new jsfiddles:

1. Logged in user [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alofthedunnes/wo2vr0ox/1/)
2. No logged in user [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alofthedunnes/72063kwt/)

And here's the relevant code:

> **navbar_style.css.scss**

```
.wrapper {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;  
}
.wrapper .navbar-default {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.wrapper .login {
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.wrapper .login .btn-group {
  color: #555;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.wrapper .login .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.wrapper .login .btn-group .btn-drop {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    left: 10px;
  }

  .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;        
  }

  .navbar-brand img {
      margin-top: 10px;
  }

}

.navbar-nav li{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar-nav > li a{
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 125%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus{
    background: #0383c0 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

> **_top_nav.html.erb (logged in user)**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row no-gutter" id="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="col-s-8">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button> 
          <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#"><img alt="Rwc 2015 logo" src="/assets/RWC-2015-logo.png" /></a> 
          <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#"><img alt="Rwc 2015 logo" src="/assets/RWC-2015-logo.png" /></a> 
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-method="get" href="/">Home</a>
            </li>

              <li><a data-method="get" href="/matches">Matches</a></li>
              <li><a data-method="get" href="/pools">Pools</a></li>
                <li><a data-method="get" href="/match_picks">Your Picks</a></li>
              <li><a data-method="get" href="/leagues">Leagues</a></li>
              <li><a data-method="get" href="/venues">Venues</a></li>



          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
      <!--end nav-->
    </div>
    <!--end col9-->
    <div class="col-s-4">
      <div class="login">


          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        testuser2@test.ie 
                  <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><a data-method="get" href="/users/edit"> Edit Account</a></a></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow"> Log Off</a>
                    </li>     

                </ul>

                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>  
            </li>

          </ul>



      </div>
      <!--end col3-->
    </div>
    <!--end row-->
  </div>
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
```

> **_top_nav.html.erb (no logged in user)**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row no-gutter" id="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="col-s-8">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button> 
          <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#"><img alt="Rwc 2015 logo" src="/assets/RWC-2015-logo.png" /></a> 
          <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#"><img alt="Rwc 2015 logo" src="/assets/RWC-2015-logo.png" /></a> 
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-method="get" href="/">Home</a>
            </li>     
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
      <!--end nav-->
    </div>
    <!--end col9-->
    <div class="col-s-4">
      <div class="login">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="/users/sign_in">Log In</a></li>
              <li><a href="/users/sign_up">Sign Up</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>

      </div>
      <!--end col3-->
    </div>
    <!--end row-->
  </div>
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
```

Comment: The basic `width` or `media-queries` given in `twitter-bootstrap` are designed keeping general devices in mind.. So I can assure you that 90% of time you will not face this issue in your devices.. Since you are allowed to resize to any extent in browser you see that as issue. So, I would suggest to go ahead and test in various devices..

Comment: I have. It's causing a problem on phones. The navbar is dropping to two rows instead of the centre column collapsing to a button

Comment: Can you mention device details?

Comment: have you set the `viewport`?

Comment: The device is an iPhone 5. I haven't set any viewport details (I'm a complete noob when it comes to front end stuff)

Comment: Anyone? I'm losing the will to program here lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how this can be done by splitting you're `navbar` between columns.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper .navbar-default {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.wrapper .login {
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.wrapper .login .btn-group {
  color: #555;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.wrapper .login .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.wrapper .login .btn-group .btn-drop {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GNOMIS</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/news">News</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="/Shop">Shop</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="/news">Toast</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
      <!--end nav-->
    </div>
    <!--end col9-->
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="login">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-drop dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">User Name <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  <span class="caret"></span>

          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li> <a href="/users/id" title="Profile">Profile</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="/logout" title="Logout">Logout </a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--end col3-->
    </div>
    <!--end row-->
  </div>
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">Bootstrap</div>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.</p>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a legend. Thank you so much for this. I can't believe how hard it was to find an example of such code.

Comment: Can I ask you a question. What exactly is making the collapse occur? I've made a few adjustments such as making the text bigger etc but the collapse always happens at the same screen width (even if text is overlapping) . I tried changing the `@media (max-width: 767px) ` but it still always collapses at the same point. I've read over all your code and understand what each is doing but I just can't figure out what is triggering the collapse. Thanks again

Comment: There are actually numerous rules in order to make everything work correctly. What width are you trying to change it to?

Comment: I'm trying to put some space to the left of the first `li` in `nav navbar-nav` i.e. "News"  and to the right of the login section. But I want to keep the grey highlighting bar showing in that space (but will be empty). About 75px on each side. But I'm not sure what exactly I should change

Comment: I'm going to adjust my op with a new jsfiddle as I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing things to drop (especially items on the right). Hopefully you can help. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah Id have to see what you're trying to do if it's not a breakpoint adjustment.

Comment: Hi vanburenx. Sorry for asking so much of you. I've been trying to sort it out myself but just can't figure out how to stop the right items from stacking on top of each other when the screen is smaller. It's doing my head in

Comment: I'm being a nuisance so I apologise in advance. Somebody showed me how the navbar is causing issues when used on the Google app on iPhone. In Safari on iPhone the left and right sections never meet. At a certain point they stop re-sizing and stay in a fixed place. But on the Google app (and also mail apps on iPhones) they overlap. The navbar also acts very strangely when using select wheels. I'm guessing a resize event keeps firing in these apps when the user zooms that doesn't on Safari. Have you ever come across this before? Is there a simple fix (besides telling them to use Safari!)

Comment: If you post a link to a production site I'll look at it when I have time.

Comment: It looks as if you've neglected to use this for one: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I'm weak on front end stuff (in my defence I've only just finished my degree) and really need to improve my skills. Any recommendations for books or resources?

Comment: Set the viewport and it destroys all my bootstrap grids on mobile. I'm not too sure how to deal with this so I think I'll tell them to use Safari until I can get my head around sizing for multiple sized devices

Comment: Viewport is only part of the issue. The custom CSS that's being used needs to be adjusted with media queries for mobile and there are extra and/or un-closed div tags throughout.

Comment: Doh! Sublime text isn't great for showing unclosed tags. Thought I had them all closed but I've obviously missed some

Comment: Sorted out all the validation errors. Completely forgot to do the validations in the first place. Schoolboy error. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: No problem. And go here http://www.lakewoodserver.com and see if this produces the same issues you are having.

Comment: I checked that on the Google app and it's not giving the same issues (right side navbar items overlapping the left side when the user zooms in). Did you add anything or is that just by setting the viewport and sorting validation issues?

Comment: No. Thats just the base css from my answer without any changes along with the viewport tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply following css in your bootstrap.css

```
.navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10 !important;
}
```

Comment: Tries this and it has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom class to the navbar which must not go multi-line:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default force-single-line-nav">
```

with css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .force-single-line-nav {
        /* hide what would be displayed on a second row of nav bar */
        max-height: 51px !important;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
}
```

That is: you simply force hide (`overflow: hidden`) anything that would go beyond the hight that you specify for your nav bar.

The `@media` query is here because on narrow screens, you're not concerned by the nav bar going multi-line: it's already taken care of by Bootstrap (expand-collapse).

Of course, you will want to adapt the `51px` and `767px` above, to your actual project's values and break points.